# Jupyter Notebook finds Octave kernel, but vscode Jupyter does not

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, octave

On Linux Mint, I could set up the Octave kernel

#### Installing

```bash
pip install jupyter
pip install octave_kernel # install octave kernel
```

`jupyter kernelspec list` prints out:

```
Available kernels:
  octave     /home/ufc/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/octave
  python3    /home/ufc/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

On Jupyter Notebook, I could find it. Howerver, o vscode, I only find these options

[image]

How can I set jupyter kernel to octave on vscode?

Answer (score 0):

Though you can not launch the octave kernel inside VSC, you can connect to a Jupyter server with an octave kernel. After launching the Jupyter server, select the **Existing Jupyter server...** from the **Select another kernel...** option and specify the URL. i.e., http://localhost:8888 for localhost.

Then you can load and execute the cells with octave code. Unfortunately, it seems that the autodetection of the programming language fails to detect Octave. However, I could manually select the language after installing the Octave extension. Here is a [screenshot of VSC with the octave kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97fGt.png). I tested with VSC 1.76.1 and JupyterLab 3.6.1.